# Source ViewController flashing after custom segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a custom segue between two view controllers. Everything works fine, except that at the end of the animation I can see the source ViewController flashing for a brief moment (very short). This doesn't happen every time.

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HorizontalSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@property CGPoint originatingPoint;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "HorizontalSegue.h"

@implementation HorizontalSegue

- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    // Add the destination view as a subview, temporarily
    [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];

    // Store original centre point of the destination view
    CGPoint originalCenter = destinationViewController.view.center;

    // Set center to start point of the button
    destinationViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.originatingPoint.x*3, self.originatingPoint.y);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         destinationViewController.view.center = originalCenter;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; // remove from temp super view
                         [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:NULL]; // present VC
                     }];
}

@end
```

Is there a way to get rid of this flash? I have tried some of the solutions presented for similar problems, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to show viewcontroller like that, adding the subviews of the destination into the current one and making animatinos with them.
There is a lot of logic involved when transitioning from one controller to another that the SDK needs to do, so its important to follow the apple guides.

Since iOS7.0 there is a complete new way to show controller with animations via UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate (which is a @property of all UIViewControllers) that lets you do any kind of animations.

There are plenty of tutorials like this

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

If however, you want to keep with the old way of embedding controllers manually, you should check "Add and Removing a Child" here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html